# DTS Package Terminates because of Duplicate Key Row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, dts

We have an old DTS Package that our SQL 2000 Server uses to push Employee records out to machines on our manufacturing floor.

Recently, we upgraded one of the machines, and it now is running SQL 2008 Express.

We have reconfigured the DTS Package to push the Employee records out to this new Server, but now we are getting this error message:

**FETCH_EMPLOYEES:**

> The statement has been terminated. Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Users' with unique index 'IX_tblUsers_OpID'.

[image: screenshot]

If I remote into our SQL 2000 Server, I can Right-Click to execute each step of the DTS Package in succession with NO errors.

[image: screenshot]

So, I log onto this machine's SQL 2008 Express instance to see if I can figure anything out.

Now I am looking at the **FETCH_EMPLOYEES** stored procedure:

```
PROCEDURE [dbo].[FETCH_EMPLOYEES] AS
DECLARE @OpID varchar(255)
DECLARE @Password varchar(50)
DECLARE Employee_Cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT OpID, Password
FROM dbo.vw_Employees
OPEN Employee_Cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor
INTO @OpID,@Password
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
insert into dbo.Users (OpID,Password,GroupID) 
VALUES (@OpID,@Password,'GROUP01')
FETCH NEXT FROM Employee_Cursor
INTO @OpID,@Password
END
CLOSE Employee_Cursor
DEALLOCATE Employee_Cursor
```

I don't really understand Cursors, but I can tell that the data is being pulled from a view called `vw_Employees` and being inserted into the table `dbo.Users`.

The view `vw_Employees` is simple:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS OpID, Num AS Password
FROM         dbo.EmployeeInfo
WHERE     (Num IS NOT NULL) AND (FirstName IS NOT NULL)
      AND (LastName IS NOT NULL) AND (Train IS NULL OR Train <> 'EX')
```

So, now it seems the problem must be from the table `dbo.Users`.

[image: screenshot]

I did not see anything particularly attention getting with this, so I scripted this table using a `CREATE TO Query Editor` and got this information that I don't really understand:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users](
[ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[OpID] [nvarchar](255) NOT NULL,
[Password] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
[GroupID] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
[IsLocked] [bit] NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_tblUsers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_tblUsers_tblGroups] FOREIGN KEY([GroupID])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Groups] ([GroupID])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_tblUsers_tblGroups]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Users] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_tblUsers_IsLocked]  DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [IsLocked]
GO
```

OK, I feel the problem is somewhere in this table definition, but I don't really understand what it is doing (after creating the basic table).

It has a CONSTRAINT section with lots of variables I do not understand, then it is altering these tables to add FOREIGN KEY and CONSTRAINTS.

My Question: Could someone help me understand what the error is telling me (other than there is some duplicate key violation).

What column could be throwing a duplicate key violation?

Did I include enough data and screenshots?

**UPDATE:**

Based on Comments, it sounds like this screenshot is needed.

In the **Users** table, there is a list of Indexes, and one called `IX_tblUsers_OpID` says it is Unique and Non-Clustered.

I think we have eliminated duplicate `Op_ID` values on our source data table `EmployeeInfo` by finding all of them with this script:

```
select num as 'Op_ID', count(num) as 'Occurrences'
from employeeInfo
group by num
having 1<count(num);
```

This *should* have gotten rid of all of my duplicates. Right?

We purchase manufacturing machines that come configured with PCs for storing local data. They supply these script I have posted up, so I cannot comment on why they picked what they did. We just run a job that pulls the data onto our server.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Bravo for attempting to provide details. In your first screenshot, the error indicates that the insert is conflicting with the unique index `IX_tblUsers_OPID`. In the script above, I don't see that index. Any chance you've scripted stuff from the wrong location?

Comment: Just because of the name of the unique index (`IX_tblUsers_OpID`), it seems to be on column `OpID` (though this doesn't seem right to me). In any case, can you post that index definition?. On another note, your sp doesn't seem to be checking the existance of the rows on that table, it just insert them all (I also don't see any reason to use a cursor there)

Comment: There is an update to the question now with a new screenshot of the `Indexes`, including one called `IX_btlUsers_OpID`. The manufacturing company supplies their machines with the databases and scripts already on them. We are just trying to plug in our old DTS Packages to these new machines.

Comment: But according to your sp, the values for `opID` come from the view, and they are compose of this: `FirstName + ' ' + LastName`, not that `num` column

Comment: Again, I did not create it. So, it is complaining about non-unique `FirstName + ' ' + LastName`?

Comment: Seems so, yes. But, as I said on a comment earlier, I don't see where are you checking for the existance of rows on your table before the `INSERT` (or do you always first delete that table?). You could be trying to insert a row that already exists

Comment: I do not see where there is any checks for the existence of a row before the `INSERT` either, but then I am not knowledgeable about DTS Packages. I'll look into resolving duplicate `FirstName + ' ' + LastName` entries from our source database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having columns with unique values has always been of high value on any dataset. This constrain can be added to any column, or index.

The error you receive is very clear and very specific. It literally gives the answer.

> The statement has been terminated. Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.Users' with unique index 'IX_tblUsers_OpID'.

It says "NO duplicates.... UNIQUE index..." then it tells you the name of the constrain "IX_tblUsers_OpID".

Now keeping that in mind, you are trying to insert in that column values you craft on the fly by concatenating two strings; name, plus last name.

What are the chances to come up with two of them being "John Smith"? High, very high!

Possible solutions:

- You may remove the constrain and allow duplicates.
- Modify the query so the values that tries to insert are -indeed- unique.
- Use 'WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON)' Reference: [index_option (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186869.aspx)

Comment: This is a good answer. I understand what you mean. The manufacturer that built the machines in our plant mapped our database's employee Name with their OpID field, and our employee Number with their Password field. That data goes back to 2004 or so. Getting each machine changed would involve sending them back to the manufacturer to be reconfigured. These are old $10m vacuum chambers for air conditioner coils. It will probably never happen. :)

Comment: I suggest you follow option 2, by modifying your view [vw_Employees]. Add the employee ID to the name: FirstName + ' ' + LastName + CAST(num AS VARCHAR(10)) AS OpID. or just use "num as OpID"  in that same view.

Comment: Wait... you should be able to change that view yourself without sending it to the manufacturer... no?

Comment: You know those clauses that say you can't tamper with another company's software? They have 10 machines from the same company. Any of them get tampered with and they refuse any work on them. It's an old question, though. I got it so that my software would prevent duplicate John Smith names (John Smith1, etc).

Comment: Ah ha! I see. Anyways, I am glad you found a solution. =)

Answer (score 0):

Another guy here at work found this hidden feature, which solves the immediate problem but could cause other unknown issues.

In the `Users` table designer view, we can Right-Click on the `OpID` column, select **Indexes/Keys...**, locate this created `IX_tblUsers_OpID` key and change it's **Is Unique** value:

[image: screenshot]

That seemed to have made it so that the DTS Package will run, and that is what we have going on right now.

I went back to the original `EmployeeInfo` table on our SQL 2000 Server to check for duplicate `OpID` values using this script:

```
select FirstName + ' ' + LastName as 'OpID',
       Count(FirstName + ' ' + LastName) as 'Occurrences'
from EmployeeInfo
group by FirstName + ' ' + LastName
having 1 < count(FirstName + ' ' + LastName)
```

...but there were no records returned.

I'm not sure why the DTS Package was failing or why we had to turn off the Unique feature.

If anyone, at some time down the road, comes up with a better fix for this, please post!